# Multiple podcasts

Tags: blog, blogger

I'd want to set up a blog that has three podcasts on different topics that you could subscribe to. I would like to add episodes to each of these podcasts as I create them.

So, I set up a Blogger account and followed directions using Feedburner to set up a podcast from my blog. So far, so good. But, now I want create the second podcast to be offered on the same site and I'm stymied. In order to create the podcast, I supply FeedBurner the site feed URL.

So how would I have multiple podcasts if I have only one site URL?

(I thought perhaps creating "pages" in my blog would give me unique page URLS which I could feed into FeedBurner, but this was a dead end.)

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create the posts for each different podcast under a different label, and then use the method [outlined here](http://www.isimplyblog.com/create-category-label-feeds-for-your-blogger-blog/156/) to have an RSS feed for each label.